# Recommended rule sets

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I'm configuring SonarQube, and I want to know whether there is any need to configure custom quality profiles in SonarQube. Maybe the default configuration is not enough?

Are there any recommended quality profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default and recommended quality profiles are named "Sonar way" (at least for SonarSource's official plugins).

Usually they are a good start - but you might want to add or remove one or another rule, after having used SonarQube for a while, depending on your project's specific needs.

Comment: Maybe also add the possibilities of additional plugins, which will not be covered with sonar way :) like findbugs etc

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I ment are there any existed recomended custom rules(maybe some rules need to be removed or added). Exact rules tuning

Comment: @Harut A "custom rule" in the SonarQube wording is a rule, created by the user (usually through the ui) by extending a rule template. Is this what you are referring to?